# Jenkins Execute Bash Based on Git Branch

Tags: git, bash, github, jenkins

I have a Jenkins project that successfully builds only when master and dev branches are pushed, and not any of our feature branches.

However, what I would like to do is have Jenkins run a different set of bash commands depending on what branch was pushed / received by Jenkins.

For example, if dev branch was pushed, deploy to test. But if master branch was pushed, deploy to production.

I've looked everywhere for someone asking something similar but have not found a solution yet, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Git Plugin store the branch which has been checked out in a variable called `GIT_BRANCH`, see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-Environmentvariables for details.

Then you can use the [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) to create a conditional build step that compares the variable value to some other value, e.g. `master` and runs a build step only when the condition evaluates to true. You can also negate the conditions, so that you can run other scripts when the branch is not the master branch.

If you also need to run conditional post-build actions, have a look at the [Flexible Publish Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Flexible+Publish+Plugin).

Answer (score 0):

I am likely missing something at the answer seems straightforward. You could check in different versions of the same bash script with your commands into each branch and then call the version of the script that you are seeing. Please explain further if you want to bounce some other ideas